# ubuntu, syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: command-line, gcc, c

I want to run a c program on ubuntu 18.04, on a virtual machine, and I get this error:

```
./test.c: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./test.c: line 3: `void main(int argc, char** argv)'
```

I compiled and ran the file like this:

```
gcc -o test test.c
./test.c
```

I gave permission to the folder using:

```
sudo chmod a+rwx
```

I've searched online, and what I know is that ( is a special character in the shell/terminal but I could not understand/find a way to use it when I write code without error.

Can someone please help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `gcc -o test test.c`  the  `test` after `-o` flag is the name of actual executable, so you need to run `./test`.  When you do `./test.c` the shell will attempt to read your C source code ( which is just text file ) as shell script and execute it according to current shell's syntax ( i.e., shell tries to read it a shell script, not as compiled C code).

On side note, please don't use `test` as name for executable. There's already `/usr/bin/test` and that can lead to confusion later. And overall using system executable names for personal programs is just bad practice